# Does Lucene.Net 4.8.0 support Azure Blob Storage to create index?

Tags: lucene.net, azure-blob-storage

I am using Lucene.Net 4.8.0 but it's not supporting to create the index and store it in Azure Blob Storage Container. Is there any workaround for that? Or have I overlooked any feature that is already available? Below is the code snippet that I used and the screen shot with the compilation error. Any solution probably with the sample code snippet will be much appreciated.

> Note: The below code is working perfectly in Lucene.Net 3.0.3.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = 
CloudStorageAccount.Parse(AzureConfig.StorageConnectionString);
IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(azureDir, indexWriterConfig);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This [AzureDirectory](https://www.fuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.Store.Azure) works with Lucene 4.8, but doesn't currently work with azure storage emulator ([this issue](https://github.com/tomlm/Lucene.Net.Store.Azure/issues/5))

The [azure-contrib AzureDirectory](https://github.com/azure-contrib/AzureDirectory) claims it update in [this issue](https://github.com/azure-contrib/AzureDirectory/issues/27), but it doesn't seem to have made it to a nuget release yet.

There is also this version, that doesn't implement directory caching https://www.fuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.Store.AzureBlob. It works with Lucene 4.8.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and we need wait or open code on github and make changes. 
If you trying to use `AzureDirectory` (like i see that) make the same path with changes on the Azure Directory. I would like advise you that the interfaces on 4.8 changes and probabily will be necessary hard work to change.